# How do you keep .NET XML parsers from expanding parameter entities in XML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dtd

When I try and parse the xml below (with code below) I keep getting `<sgml>&question;&signature;</sgml>`

expanded to

```
<sgml>Why couldn’t I publish my books directly in standard SGML? — William Shakespeare.</sgml>
```

OR

```
<sgml></sgml>
```

Since I am working on an XML 3-way Merging algorithm I would like to retrieve the un-expanded 
`<sgml>&question;&signature;</sgml>`

I have tried:

- Parsing the xml normaly (this results in the expanded sgml tag)
- Removing the Doctype from the beginning on the xml this results in empty sgml tag)
- Various XmlReader DTD settings

I have the following XML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE sgml [
  <!ELEMENT sgml ANY>
  <!ENTITY  std       "standard SGML">
  <!ENTITY  signature " &#x2014; &author;.">
  <!ENTITY  question  "Why couldn&#x2019;t I publish my books directly in &std;?">
  <!ENTITY  author    "William Shakespeare">
]>
<sgml>&question;&signature;</sgml>
```

Here is the code I have tried (several attempts):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string xml = @"C:\src\Apps\Wit\MergingAlgorithmTest\MergingAlgorithmTest\Tests\XMLMerge-DocTypeExpansion\DocTypeExpansion.0.xml";
        var xmlSettingsIgnore = new XmlReaderSettings 
            {
                CheckCharacters = false,
                DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Ignore
            };

        var xmlSettingsParse = new XmlReaderSettings
        {
            CheckCharacters = false,
            DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse
        };

        using (var fs = File.Open(xml, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            using (var xmkReaderIgnore = XmlReader.Create(fs, xmlSettingsIgnore))
            {
                // Prevents Exception "Reference to undeclared entity 'question'"
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = xmkReaderIgnore.GetType().GetProperty("DisableUndeclaredEntityCheck", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(xmkReaderIgnore, true, null);

                var doc = XDocument.Load(xmkReaderIgnore);

                Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.ToString()); // outputs <sgml></sgml> not <sgml>&question;&signature;</sgml>
            }// using xml ignore

            fs.Position = 0;
            using (var xmkReaderIgnore = XmlReader.Create(fs, xmlSettingsParse))
            {
                var doc = XDocument.Load(xmkReaderIgnore);
                Console.WriteLine(doc.Root.ToString()); // outputs <sgml>Why couldn't I publish my books directly in standard SGML? - William Shakespeare.</sgml> not <sgml>&question;&signature;</sgml>
            }

            fs.Position = 0;
            string parseXmlString = String.Empty;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) // Skip DocType
                    sr.ReadLine();

                parseXmlString = sr.ReadLine();
            }

            using (XmlReader xmlReaderSkip = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(parseXmlString),xmlSettingsParse))
            {
                // Prevents Exception "Reference to undeclared entity 'question'"
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = xmlReaderSkip.GetType().GetProperty("DisableUndeclaredEntityCheck", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                propertyInfo.SetValue(xmlReaderSkip, true, null);

                var doc2 = XDocument.Load(xmlReaderSkip); // Empty sgml tag

            }
        }//using FileStream
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use an amphersand.  See following webpage : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: This is valid xml, the ampersand represents a parameter reference the DTD in the xml makes this legal.  Please see this: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xmlnut/ch03_04.htm

Comment: Yes, but not "&question;&signature".  The items in square brackets are ok.

Comment: how is that different from the &super; example in my link and "In contrast, a character entity reference refers to a character by the name of an entity which has the desired character as its replacement text. The entity must either be predefined .... or explicitly declared in a Document Type Definition (DTD). The format is the same as for any entity reference:
&name;
where name is the case-sensitive name of the entity. The semicolon is required" in your link?

Comment: You don't have !DOCTYPE sgml [....].  So the wiki link I provided prevails.

Comment: I do have a !Doctype sgml in the sample xml I posted.  Where are you saying I am missing doctype?

Comment: <sgml>&question;&signature;</sgml>

Comment: That is not the full xml file I am using, just a snippet.  I think you are missing where I said that <sgml>&question;&signature;</sgml> gets expanded to ... OR ...  The section under "I have the following xml file:" is the xml that I am using which does have a doc type element.

Comment: It is the XML viduslizer in VS that is expanding the textc.  The original text is still there.  If you look at the text with Text Visualizer it is ok, but with XML Visualizer the text is converted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq-to-XML does not support modeling of entity references -- they are automatically expanded to their values ([source 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20150109020618/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2010/01/21/writing-entity-references-using-linq-to-xml.aspx), [source 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q47v5BAGiC4C&pg=PT85&lpg=PT85&dq=linq+to+XML+equivalent+of+XmlEntityReference&source=bl&ots=Z5LVSW7zuW&sig=uS-qYGKKg-hR29-FLLYeDSmxw-A&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SvRtVaG3HvK0sAS5toKICQ&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=linq%20to%20XML%20equivalent%20of%20XmlEntityReference&f=false)).  There simply is no subclass of [`XObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) defined for a general entity reference.

However, assuming your XML is valid (i.e. the entity references exist in the DTD, which they do in your example) you can use the *old [XML Document Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9hbf87%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)* to parse your XML and insert [`XmlEntityReference`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlentityreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) nodes into your XML DOM tree, rather than expanding the entity references into plain text:

```
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(xml))
        using (var xtr = new XmlTextReader(sr))
        {
            xtr.EntityHandling = EntityHandling.ExpandCharEntities; // Expands character entities and returns general entities as System.Xml.XmlNodeType.EntityReference
            var oldDoc = new XmlDocument();
            oldDoc.Load(xtr);
            Debug.WriteLine(oldDoc.DocumentElement.OuterXml); // Outputs <sgml>&question;&signature;</sgml>
            Debug.Assert(oldDoc.DocumentElement.OuterXml.Contains("&question;")); // Verify that the entity references are still there - no assert
            Debug.Assert(oldDoc.DocumentElement.OuterXml.Contains("&signature;")); // Verify that the entity references are still there - no assert
        }
```

the [`ChildNodes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of each `XmlEntityReference` will have the text value of the general entity.  If a general entity refers to other general entities, as one does in your case, the corresponding inner `XmlEntityReference` will be nested in the `ChildNodes` of the outer.  You can then compare the old and new XML using the old `XmlDocument` API.

Note you also need to use the old [`XmlTextReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextreader.entityhandling%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set [`EntityHandling = EntityHandling.ExpandCharEntities`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.entityhandling%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).