# Do not decode escaped characters when reading XML with XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML that contains attribute strings containing escaped characters such as `&lt;`.

After reading such a file with `XDocument` and accessing the attribute content using `.Value`, all such escaped characters get decoded. `.Value` will return a string containing `<`, not `&lt;`.

Is there a way of keeping the raw text contained in the XML strings, not decoding them?

Comment: If xml strings doesn't contains both, escaped `&lt;` and unescaped `<`, then you can simply read attribute value as you do and escape it. It seems there is [`InnerXml` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1132533/1997232), perhaps you can just use `XmlDocument`?

Comment: You can escape it using something like `new XText(x.Value).ToString()`, though there's no guarantee the result will be identical to the source.

Comment: I've spent quite some time once trying to do that (right as you describe - avoid expanding all xml entities including character entities), without any success.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do  this with `XDocument`.  There is some ability to do this with the old `XmlDocument` and `XmlTextReader` however, see [How do you keep .NET XML parsers from expanding parameter entities in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30598841) and [Entity References are Expanded and Not Preserved](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/entity-references-are-expanded-and-not-preserved).

Answer (score -2):

It is not very beautiful, but I use this:

```
var attributeText = attribute.ToString();
attributeText = attributeText.TrimPrefix(attributeName);
attributeText = attributeText.TrimStart('=');
attributeText = attributeText.Trim('\"');
```